# Different thumbnails for index and article page

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

For my aricles (wp7app.de) I'd like to use two different thumbnails, one which is displayed only on the index page (150x150) and one for the article page (600x400). However, I don't want to use a cropped version of the big image for the index. 
Is this something that can be done easily without an extra plugin or can you recommend a good / simple one?
Cheers

Comment: Well, if you want the size of thumbnail type #1 to be 150x150 (which is aspect ratio 1:1) and type #2 should be 600x400 (which is 2:3, or 1:1,5, if you will) and you don't want to crop the image, you have (maybe) hideous stretching effects. Do you already have the two different thumbnail sizes or are you also looking for a way to create these?

Comment: currently I crop the 600x400 image manually to get the 150x150 for the index. But I want to use two completly different Images, one for the index and one for the main article page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the "Multiple Post Thumbnails" plugin which I'm quite happy with:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a template for the pages that you want a bigger thumbnail for and call a bigger thumbnail in the code of that template.

Comment: each post will have one big and one small image. The small one will be shown with the summary on my index page, the big one will be shown when I read the full article.